# Trying to replace chars in csv, then write modified file to filesystem

Tags: powershell

I have a csv with in the 11th column a value for which I want to make a replace, and then write the modified file to filesystem:

```
get-content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | % { $_.Split(",")[11] -replace "1", "@" } | out-file stuffs.csv
```

I would expect `stuffs.csv` to have the input file, but with all `1`s replaces by `@` for the 11th column. However, it ONLY contains the 11th column.

How what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your expectation is incorrect.

```
get-content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | % { $_.Split(",")[11] -replace "1", "@" }
```

The above line says: `$_.Split(",")[11]`, which means get the 12th column. Nowhere to do you select **all** the columns. From there you are doing the replace and that's what you are piping to the output file. In psuedo code, you've said "Get the contents of the csv. For each row, get the 12th column, replace "1" with "@", output the replaced value."

You would need something more along the lines of:

```
get-content .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv | % { $sheet = $_.Split(","); $sheet[11] = $sheet[11] -replace "1", "@"; $_ } | out-file stuffs.csv
```

However, if you have any quoted strings (like 1,2,"This is a string, yay!", Four, 5), your `Split` won't work. You should investigate the commands `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`. These will give you more control over your input and output.

For example:

```
$sheet = Import-Csv .\BSEG_EXPORT.csv

foreach ($row in $sheet) {
    $row.11thColumnName = $row.11thColumnName.Replace("1", "@")
}

$sheet | Export-Csv stuffs.csv
```